# Best way to pass default parameter in templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Sometimes inside my templates I want to define default values for some CSS properties when those values are not passed as parameters in the render function, like this:

```
height: <%= if @height do %><%=@height%><% else %>"50px";<%end%>
```

I'm wondering if there's a better (less verbose) way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that

1. `@` variables can also be accessed through a map named `assigns`,
2. accessing a non-existent key in a map using the bracket syntax returns nil instead of raising an exception,
3. `||` returns the right hand side value if the left one is `nil`,

and write:

```
<%= assigns[:height] || "50px" %>
```

to get the same behavior as your `if`/`else`.

Edit: if you're always setting `@height`, even if the value is `nil`, you can do this with even lesser code:

```
<%= @height || "50px" %>
```

The previous code will work even if `@height` is not set to any value but this will raise an exception if `@height` is not set.